# Linq query for distinct data from a table with where condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have an sql statement like this:

```
select distinct(agent_name)
from properties
where agent_name not in ('null','')
```

I want the linq query in C# page

Comment: Is `'null'` supposed to be a string value or literally `null`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're comparing to the string value `'null'` like your original query:

```
List<string> agentNames = db.Properties.Where(p=>p.AgentName != "null" && 
                                        p.AgentName != "")
                                       .Select(p => p.AgentName)
                                       .Distinct()
                                       .ToList();
```

If you're actually comparing to a null value just change it to:

```
List<string> agentNames = db.Properties.Where(p=>p.AgentName != null && 
                                        p.AgentName != "")
                                       .Select(p => p.AgentName)
                                       .Distinct()
                                       .ToList();
```

Comment: I want data to List not in var

Comment: Added `.ToList()` and specified type rather than using `var`.  FYI `var` is not a "type" it's short syntax to let the compiler decide what the type is.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = context.Properties.Where(p => p.AgentName != null 
                                        && p.AgentName != "")
                               .GroupBy(p => p.AgentName)
                               .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
   var result =    (from dbo in database.Table
                     where dbo.agent_name!=null and dbo.agent_name !=''
                     select dbo.agent_name).Distinct();
```

or if you have a list already

```
  var result = (list.Where(a => a.agent_name!=null && a.agent_name!='').Select(
                a.agent_name)).Distinct();
```

Comment: Linq to Entities doesn't support `String.IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: @NinjaNye: Thanks, fixed it :) so used to `ienumerable`

Comment: Why are you creating the new object rather than just selecting `agent_name`?

Comment: I want data to List not in var

Comment: @kabijoy: var can be any type, please have a look [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
var forms = db.properties.
                Where(a => a.agent_name == 'null' || a.agent_name == null).
                Select(x => x.agent_name).
                Distinct().
                ToList();
```

Its equivalent SQL statement, which is designed by LINQ to SQL is

```
SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[agent_name] AS [agent_name]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[agent_name] AS [agent_name]
        FROM [dbo].[properties] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[agent_name] = N'null' OR [Extent1].[agent_name] = N''
    )  AS [Distinct1]
```